# The Security to the Party [Part 20]

Tags: mathematics, password

A party is being held at a local mansion. The host is very rich and his success is because of one thing — his famous recipe for Spaghetti!

The only guests that may attend are people who correctly reply to the guard at the door.

Here's where you come in. You and a friend are trying to steal this recipe. You sneak by and listen to the passwords.

The first guest arrives.  The guard says, "1", the guest replies "2" and is let in.

The second guest arrives.  The guard says, "3", the guest replies "5" and is let in.

The third guest arrives.  The guard says, "8", the guest replies "4" and is let in.

Your friend says, "Aha!  This is an easy one."   He slips away and show up at the gate a minute later.  "13", the guard says.  Your friend replies "3" and is immediately trampled by an elephant.

Where did your friend go wrong?

Hint:

> You decide to hang around a bit longer.
>  The next guest arrives, and the guard says, "2".  The guest replies "2" and is let in.

Second Hint:

> Another guest arrives, and the guard says "89".  The guest replies "8" and get in.

Final hint:

> Still scratching your head, you wait for another guest to approach. "Two" you hear the guard start to say, but at that exact moment a passing truck honks somewhere behind you, nearly startling you out from the tree.  You barely recover in time to hear the guest reply, "8" and the guard lets her in.

Having read the above hints, now you decide to approach the guard.  He says, "34", what do you reply?

As usual please post your answer, an explanation of what process you used to get the answer and any hints used in spoiler tags.

Note: Whoops, flubbed the final hint. It should be correct now.

Comment: what will happen for the guest you mentioned in hint?

Comment: @Rafe Ah sorry, I forgot that; added.

Comment: I don't even understand how the friend (which picks obvious answers) got 3!

Comment: Is the answer 18? I have no explanation do I cannot form an answer.

Comment: @warspyking 18 is not the answer, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure that when the guard says 8, the answer is 4, not 5?

Comment: @Victor The correct answer for 8 is 4.  How on Earth did you get 5?

Comment: @Michael, by using an algorithm that is probably the wrong one. lol

Comment: Second hint is indeed very helpful, but couldn't crack it yet. :(

Comment: @Victor I've got one more hint that I could give but I'm afraid it might make the answer much more obvious.

Comment: I am posting an answer (probably wrong), but maybe I did cracked it. I am explaining what I did to get it.

Comment: this is complex, even with all the hints I can't solve it

Comment: @Victor has mentioned the Fibonacci series. That was great. and my guess is that "Two...." is 233, 12th number of the series. (or with low probability, 2584)

Comment: @Rafe, yeah, got to the same conclusion. However no matter what I do, I can't make sense of the numbers. Already tried counting the letters of its Fibonacci position, but that fails for 89 and "two..."

Comment: I gave up and going to bed! happy puzzling @Victor

Comment: I don't get why 233 and 89 have the same result.. My brain starting to hurt.. :<

Comment: @Emi987 Understanding why 233 and 89 have the same result is the key to solving the other half of the puzzle!

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not post any comment since its requires 50 or more rep, feel free to remove this if you want I see some thing wrong with your question: 1 - If the answer for each guest base on previous answer - How do they know them? 2 - Assume they have been invited in an order and know what previous question-answer Then why the 4th REAL guest arrive after your friend (been trampled by an elephant) been ask the same question of your friend( aka "13")?

Comment: 1. The answer for each guest is not based on the previous answer, only on the question (challenge number) given by the guard.  2. The guest after your friend did not get the same question as your friend did.

Answer (score 2):

Most patterns I'm getting seem to point me at

> **7**, but I can't find the pattern that fits perfectly.
>
>  I know it's got to have something to do with the Fibonacci numbers and particularly their indices in the series, but I just can't seem to crack it...
>
>  Another hint maybe?

Comment: That's the correct answer to 34, but can you tell me why?

Comment: It was the only answer that seemed to match the patterns of the others, given that 8 was deemed incorrect (so I cheated!) My closest guess was that the answer was the corresponding index of the given number in sequence, minus an amount equal to the number of digits of the initially given number. But that only matched up for about half or so of the given scenarios...

Answer (score 2):

Ok Here's my friends try:

> 34 = 7
>
>  1=2
>
>  2=2
>
>  3=5
>
>  5=8
>
>  8=13=1+3=4
>
>  13=4
>
>  21=3
>
>  34=7
>  ...
>  89=8+9=17=1+7=8
>
>  How it works:
>  The number given is one of Fibonacci numbers
>  If it have 1 char => return next number from Fibonacci
>  If it have 2 char => plus them together

And now 21 is not 3, I guess luckily the guard didn't give me 21 :D

Comment: I think that you got it.

Comment: Everything is right except for one thing: the correct response to 21 is not 3.

Comment: It might help to more explicitly state the general relationship between the numbers, instead of just enumerating it for each input.

Comment: I really don't know how to make that text shade ....

Comment: Your explanation is not quite correct, which is why you aren't getting the right response for 21.

Comment: Also, the correct explanation works for any number characters in the number, not just 1 or 2.

Comment: By your logic, the answer for 2 should be 3 but it is given that that the answer for 2 is 2.

Answer (score 1):

My answer:

> The guard always asks a number from the Fibonacci series:
>
>  [1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 5, 5 -> ???, 8 -> 4, 13 -> ??? (not 3), 21 -> ???, 34 -> ???, 55 -> ???, 89 -> 8]
>
>  2 is the 2nd answer of the series, which maps to a value that is the double of the 1st answer.
>  89 is the 10th answer of the series, which maps to 8, the double of the 5th answer, which is 4.
>  The answer for 34 should be the double of the answer for 5, which is the double of the answer of 2.
>  So the answer is **8**.

EDIT: Wrong answer! I was trampled by an elephant. :(

Comment: You are definitely on the right track, but haven't got all the details quite right, and your answer to "34" is incorrect.

Comment: If I could do a >! spoiler in a comment I would add an extra hint "just" for you (or anyone reading your answer).

Comment: Ok, put it in question. If you think it might be too easy, try to produce a harder one, even if it is in the form of "you couldn't understand what the guard did said, because a truck in the street honked just in that moment, but the answer given by the guest was X".

Comment: Trunk honking that's great!  I've added a final hint.

Comment: Whoops, re-read the updated final hint, I flubbed it the first time.

Comment: @Michael, the previous final hint was wrong?

Comment: yes, i flubbed it up. it's fixed now.

Comment: Hmmm, can't understand why 3 maps to 5... Still making my neurons work.

Comment: @d'alar'cop Already sent it some minutes ago.